# Copy Text from Quicklook

Tags: macos, quicklook

In previous versions of OS X a plist addition to `com.apple.finder` (outlined [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/copying-text-from-a-file-using-quick-look) for instance) could be used to enable select and copy in quicklook previews.

This (hidden) feature doesn't appear to work anymore in Mavericks. Any workarounds? Or is the setting merely named differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running

```
defaults write -g QLEnableTextSelection -bool true
```

and relaunching applications works for me. `defaults write com.apple.finder QLEnableTextSelection -bool true` only applies to Finder but `defaults write -g QLEnableTextSelection -bool true` applies to all applications.

If it doesn't work, see what Quick Look generator handles plain text files:

```
$ qlmanage -m|grep public.plain-text
  public.plain-text -> /System/Library/QuickLook/Text.qlgenerator (555.0)
```

If it is not `Text.qlgenerator`, try to delete it and run `qlmanage -r`.

Comment: Deleting the third party generator and running `qlmanage -r` worked. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with `qlmanage -p` on 10.8.5.

Comment: @Dominique Did you run `defaults write -g QLEnableTextSelection -bool true`? `defaults write com.apple.Finder QLEnableTextSelection -bool true` only applies to Finder and not to `qlmanage`.

Comment: Yes I did. I think this trick works when you use QuickLook from the Finder, but not when you call `qlmanage -p` from the command line.

Comment: I'm using 10.9 Running defaults write -g QLEnableTextSelection -bool true does not work for me

Answer (score 2):

Please notice that the activation of the "Text-Selection-In-Quicklook"-Feature could lead to the bug described in this question:

[QuickLook blanks when displaying some images](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128825/quicklook-having-problems-displaying-some-images)